# Read json in fetch with javascript

Tags: javascript

Below is code for fetch in javascript:

```
 fetch(url + "?" + o)
   .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        resolve(response.text());
      } else {
      reject(response.json());  ///issue in read json data  how to read json?
                       
    }
 })
 .then(html => {
     debugger
     document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = html;
 })
 .catch(err => {
   debugger
   console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err)
                    ´ 
   document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = err;
 });
```

I need to read json if (!response.ok) i need to read the json data in catch or any where just div need to updated..

Return Json format:

```
{ success = false, message = "Operation failed." }
```

How to read json in fetch?

EDIT : server return succees in html and failure( error) in json ..html working fine and i need parse json data if failure case show in div

Comment: *"Reutrn Json format"* That isn't [JSON](https://json.org).

Comment: sory i am using c# ,,, it has 2 property success  and message

Comment: `resolve(response.text());` ... what is `resolve` - it's not defined anywhere ... perhaps you meant `return response.text();`? as that is how Promises chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've shown, you're trying to use `resolve` and `reject` identifiers that haven't been declared anywhere (that you've shown).

To settle the promise returned by `then` from within its callback, use `return` to return a value (or a promise to resolve to) or `throw` (or a rejected promise).

In a comment you've said:

> Actually server return succees in html and failure( error) in json ..i need parse json data if failure case show in div

To handle that, I think I'd convert the server's error object into an `Error` and throw it; see comments:

```
fetch(url + "?" + o)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            // Read the HTML that comes with success
            return response.text();
        } else {
            // Read the JSON that comes with the error,
            // then use it as an error
            return response.json()
            .then(serverError => {
                throw new Error(serverError.message);
            });
        }
    })
    .then(html => {
        // Here, you have the HTML result
        document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = html;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Here you have either a network error or an error
        // we caught above and used to create an Error instance
        document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = err.message || String(err);
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much ..Actually server return succees  in html and failure( error) in json ..i need  parse json  data if failure case show in div

Comment: @Ajt - Ah! I understand now. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Ajt - Re your suggested edit: The `err` object will be the `Error` thrown from the first `then` callback, which will have a `message` property on it, so the code is correct as-is.